# Pass key-value pairs of object as individual arguments to component in Angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, frontend, angular-components

Assume i have a component that takes three inputs `input1`, `input2` and `input3`

```
export class testComponent {
  @Input() input1:string;
  @Input() input2:string;
  @Input() input3:string;
  ....
  ...
}
```

In the parent component I have object like

```
args = {
    input1: "string1",
    input2: "string2",
    input3: "string3"
}
```

what is the best way to pass these key value pairs in object as arguments to the `testComponent`.
All the inputs to `testComponent` are not mandatory and the `args` sometimes might not have all the arguments.

I don't want the `testComponent` to take object itself as the input. Pls suggest some ideas. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually, it's a limitation of Angular, like **we cannot de-structure** the object (`...args`) on the html tag and the child component will read the values like how React does!

```
<app-test [input1]="args?.input1" [input2]="args?.input2" [input3]="args?.input3"/>
```

Comment: I've though of this approach but as I said, the `args` variable might not have all the parameters and it is passed as input to parent component (so there is no way of knowing which keys exist). if `input3` doesn't exist, then this approach throws error.

Comment: @NithishKumar You can just null check the function to get rid of the console error on the child component! Try using typescript `?.` to auto null check easily on the TS code! When you lookup `args?.input1` even if input1 does not exist, you will not get any errors by using this method!

Answer (score 1):

In Naren Murali's answer, conditional chaining is unnecessary because arguments always exist; Actually, it should be like the following:

**Parent component**

```
<app-test 
  [input1]="args.input1" 
  [input2]="args.input2" 
  [input3]="args.input3"
></app-test>
```

**Child component**

```
export class testComponent {
  @Input() input1: string | undefined;
  @Input() input2: string | undefined;
  @Input() input3: string | undefined;
}
```

If you want to guarantee the string type of the inputs, you must define a default value, such as:

**Child component**

```
export class testComponent {
  @Input() input1 = '';
  @Input() input2 = '';
  @Input() input3 = '';
}
```